# error 2110 setfocus on bound combobox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I use the following code on the click event of a button on my form:

```
...
'Make the appropriate location appear in the combobox
For i = 0 To cboLocations.ListCount - 1
  If Me.cboLocations.Column(0, i) = locindex Then        
    Me.cboLocations.SetFocus
    Me.cboLocations.Value = Me.cboLocations.Column(1, i)
    Me.cboLocations.Selected(i) = True
    Exit For
  End If
Next i
...
```

This works as expected when using the button, but when I attempt to execute the very same code in some other subroutine, the SetFocus line triggers the error 2110: Access can't move the focus to the control cboLocations.  That doesn't make sense to me.  Why does it work in one place and not in another?